# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS }

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a code that checks for the current location, however, when I check for the current location, it crashes. I looked into Stack Trace and saw this. I read other forums but I am not familiar with their solutions. I am also a beginner in Java. I used an Amazon Fire Tablet to download this app. When I tried testing it on the emulator, the app did not crash.

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1797)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3761)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4032)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4000)
        at com.example.calculatorandlocationfinderfinal.MainActivity$7.onClick(MainActivity.java:181)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Below is the code where it happened.

```java
private void onGPS() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS));
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use this method to start intents other than your app's -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
if(intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    //handle activity not found
}
```

this way you won't get ActivityNotFoundException.

You can also use try catch as -

```
try {
       startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
       //handle activity not found
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to navigate to GPS settings screen.
try this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

The phone/device might be missing locale settings screen altogether which leads to the crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //This line solve my issue
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).